# Logical Indexing with Python's map

Tags: python, python-3.x

**TL DR:** How can I best use `map` to `filter` a list based on logical indexing?

Given a list:

```
values = ['1', '2', '3', '5', 'N/A', '5']
```

I would like to `map` the following function and use the result to `filter` my list. I could do this with `filter` and other methods but mostly looking to learn if this can be done solely using `map`.

The function:

```
def is_int(val):
    try:
        x = int(val)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Attempted solution:

```
[x for x in list(map(is_int, values)) if x is False]
```

The above gives me the values I need. However, it does not return the index or allow logical indexing. I have tried to do other ridiculous things like:

```
[values[x] for x  in list(map(is_int, values)) if x is False]
```

and many others that obviously don't work.

**What I thought I could do:**

```
values[[x for x in list(map(is_int, values)) if x is False]]
```

**Expected outcome**:

```
['N/A']
```

Comment: You cannot use `map()` alone to perform a reduction. By its very definition, `map()` preserves the number of items https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function) . On the other hand, reduce operations are meant to be doing what you want. In Python these may be implemented normally with a generator expression or for the more functional-style inclined programmers, with `filter()`. Other non-primitive approach may exist, but they essentially boil down to one of the two.

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant to use the result of `map` like so: `values[result of map]` to return the result not literally use `map` to filter.

Comment: Oh OK, that is a bit different then. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the expected outcome using the simple snippet written below which does not involve any map function

```
[x for x in values if is_int(x) is False]
```

And, if you want to strictly use `map` function then the snippet below will help you

```
[values[i] for i,y in enumerate(list(map(is_int,values))) if y is False]
```

Comment: Ah, I just thought of using enumerate right now. Is the latter solution computationally efficient though?

Comment: Yeah, enumerate will be the most simple and helpful tool for this question

Comment: How is `enumerate` more simple than a simple list comprehension? Also, better do `if not x` instead of `if x is False`. Also, you can `enumerate` the `map` directly, no need for `list`.

Answer (score 5):

```
[v for v in values if not is_int(v)]
```

If you have a parallel list of booleans:

```
[v for v, b in zip(values, [is_int(x) for x in values]) if not b]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use `map`? I am mostly asking to learn about how flexible `map` is since I'm new to `python`. If not, why can't we use `map` here? Sorry if it's too broad.

Comment: @NelsonGon In Python, [list comprehensions are generally preferred to `map`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map); if you are new to Python I would encourage you to "get on with it" even if other languages prefer a map-like construct. (There should be a way to make it through `map`, though.)

Comment: Thanks @Leporello I will get used to comprehensions then.

Comment: Or `[v for v, b in zip(values, map(is_int, values)) if not b]`.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is just not the right tool for the job, as that would transform the values, whereas you just want to check them. If anything, you are looking for `filter`, but you have to "inverse" the filter-function first:

```
>>> values = ['1', '2', "foo", '3', '5', 'N/A', '5']                       
>>> not_an_int = lambda x: not is_int(x)                                   
>>> list(filter(not_an_int, values))                                       
['foo', 'N/A']
```

In practice, however, I would rather use a list comprehension with a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a bit of help from `itertools` and by negating the output of your original function since we want it to return `True` where it is not an int.

```
from itertools import compress
from operator import not_

list(compress(values, map(not_, map(is_int, values))))

['N/A']
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `map()` alone to perform a reduction. By its very definition, map() preserves the number of items (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function))).
On the other hand, reduce operations are meant to be doing what you want. In Python these may be implemented normally with a generator expression or for the more functional-style inclined programmers, with filter(). Other non-primitive approach may exist, but they essentially boil down to one of the two, e.g.:

```py
values = ['1', '2', '3', '5', 'N/A', '5']

list(filter(lambda x: not is_int(x), values))
# ['N/A']
```

Yet, if what you want is to combine the result of `map()` to use it for within slicing, this cannot be done with Python alone.
However, NumPy supports precisely what you want except that the result will not be a list:

```py
import numpy as np

np.array(values)[list(map(lambda x: not is_int(x), values))]
# array(['N/A'], dtype='<U3')
```

(Or you could have your own container defined in such a way as to implement this behavior).

---

That being said, it is quite common to use the following generator expression in Python in place of `map()` / `filter()`.

```
filter(func, items)
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
item for item in items if func(item)
```

while

```
map(func, items)
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
func(item) for item in items
```

and their combination:

```
filter(f_func, map(m_func, items))
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
m_func(item) for item in items if f_func(item)
```

Comment: The `numpy` solution looks great. I have unfortunately already accepted an answer(don't like de-accepting if that's a word) but thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `not is_int(x)` in the first `filter`? You are missing the `(x)`.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, sorry it just went missing while typing. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I had in mind but something I learnt from this problem, we could do the following(which might be computationally less efficient). This is almost similar to @aws_apprentice 's answer. Clearly one is better off using `filter` and/or list comprehension:

```
from itertools import compress
list(compress(values, list(map(lambda x: not is_int(x), values))))
```

Or as suggested by @aws_apprentice simply:

```
from itertools import compress
list(compress(values, map(lambda x: not is_int(x), values)))
```

Comment: you don't need the intermediate call to `list`, the `map` object alone will suffice

Comment: Oh woow, thanks. I really have a long way to go but I found this a cool feature.